# Shiny datatable how to change theme

Tags: r, shiny, themes, dt

I would like to apply a dark theme to a shiny application:

```
    library(shinythemes)

    shinyUI(fluidPage(
      theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
     ...)
```

But the DT datatable does not follow the theme color.

How can I make it dark ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you should switch the DT to bootstrap style so that the css is applied to the table aslo. Use `style = 'bootstrap'` in your DT call.

Comment: OK, thanks, now I understand. Download and copy bootstrap.css to the directory, and call DT with style = 'bootstrap' . Thanks

Comment: Just set the style to bootstrap in the datable call, all the rest is already there.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to your posted code, you must also add the following argument to your `datatable` function. Fully reproducible code below.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
    output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(iris,
                style = "bootstrap" # <--------- This is the crucial part
      )
    })
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```